# Inheritance. Use of super() confusion

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm stumped.  When the client code (see bottom) is run, I think the line super.testIt() should produce "it" and not "up", thus giving **upitit** as the correct answer. I coded it in and ran it, and **upupit** is the correct answer.  Why does a super method call go back down to the child's method?

```
public class V
{
  public void one(){
     System.out.print("it");
  }
  public void two(){
     System.out.print("go");
  }
  public void testIt(){
     one();
  }  
}

public class W extends V
{
  public void one(){
     System.out.print("up");
  }
  public void two(){
     System.out.print("at");
  }
  public void testIt(){
     one();
     super.testIt();
     super.one();
  }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//client code in the main of another class
W x = new W();
x.testIt();
```

Comment: Because that's the entire idea of virtual methods...

Comment: I get what you're saying, but since there is a one() method in each class, can you explain why the child's one method is invoked rather than the parents?  Most of my students picked upitit, so there's compelling reason why beginning coders would get confused.

Comment: Because the object is of type `W`, and `W` overrides `one()`, so `W.one()` is invoked.

Comment: Why are people downvoting this? What exactly is the problem with the question? It is clearly worded and succinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying class is a W. Due to polymorphism, it will call the W's one() method.

Comment: I understand why the call to one() would call W's one() method (duh.) But why doesn't super.testIt() call the super's one() method, and therefore output "it"? Sorry, this is actually confusing to me too...

Comment: super.testIt() call base class method testIt(), but, inside testIt() of one() won't call base class, because derived class override that method.

Comment: @EJP I understand that, yes. But super.testIt() puts us into that first testIt() method in V, right? And that testIt() method calls one(). That should be equivalent to calling this.one(). In this context, correct me if I'm wrong, "this" refers to V? Or does "this" refer to whatever called the method originally? If so, I never heard of that feature of Java before. But I could just be confused. If "this" does refer to V, then the V one() method should print out "it". What am I missing here?

Comment: @Keara No, `super.testIt()` calls *the object's* `one()` method, and the object is type `W`. Also, `this` refers to an object, not a class.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex Ah, ok. Thank you. Could somebody please make an answer with all of that explanation in detail, because I was super confused by this. And I have an ok amount of experience with Java, too... yikes. Thanks y'all.

Comment: @Keara It's difficult to see where the confusion could possibly be. What part of 'it will call the `W`'s `one()` method' didn't you understand? The comment posted by @ChaiT.Rex is correct but it doesn't contain anything that isn't already stated in the answer.

Comment: I get it.  Appreciate the fast replies.  I have enough here to help my students.